how can i used django on python 3.13?
am trying to install Django on Python 3.13 but am getting this problem
(action) PS C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP> python -m django --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from django.core import management
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
    ...<4 lines>...
    )
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.core import checks
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    import django.core.checks.caches  # NOQA isort:skip
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\caches.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS, caches
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\core\cache\__init__.py", line 67, in <module>
    signals.request_finished.connect(close_caches)
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\dispatch\dispatcher.py", line 87, in connect
    if settings.configured and settings.DEBUG:
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\desktop\AVP\action\Lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 83, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(_wrapped, name)
          ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'

i tried uninstalling the existing Django the installing it again but all in vail

which django version do u use?

Why are you trying to use Django with a version of Python which isn't even released?

Are you using a virtual environment? If not learn about them. Install a supported version of Python natively. Create a virtual environment. Develop and test in it. Create another virtual environment, or several, and apply upgrades  to test the same code base with upgraded Python (or upgraded anything else).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Python 3.13 is not yet released and will be released on October 1, 2024.
The stable release of Django (i.e. 5.1) currently supports Python 3.10 - 3.12
To install the stable release of Django, run:
pip install Django

Please use a supported version of Python. See What Python version can I use with Django?
